# Rising tuition cost after ten years

Tags: java

> Suppose that the tuition for a university is $10,000 this year and increases 5% every year. In one year, the tuition will be $10,500. Write a program that computes the tuition in ten years and the total cost of four years' worth of tuition after the tenth year.

I can calculate the tenth year tuition easily enough. What has me stumped is how to add the unique tuition values at years 11, 12, 13 and 14.

```
double Fee = 10000;
double Year = 1;
double TotalFee;
double Rate = 5;
double TotalCost = 15000 + 15500 + 16000 + 16500;

System.out.println("Year   "  + " Total Fee  ");
System.out.println();

while (Year <= 14) {
    TotalFee = Fee + ((Fee * ((Year * Rate) - Rate)) / 100);
    System.out.println(Year + "  " + "       "+ TotalFee);` 
    Year++;
}

System.out.println("Total cost tuition of 4 years starting 10 years from now is " + TotalCost);
```

The last while loop is my attempt at adding the 4 years. How could I pull out the unique values of TotalCost at iterations 11 to 14 and add them?

Comment: i guess you want to use [compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest). You actually didn´t calculate anything and the values are probably wrong aswell

Comment: Why is the value `TotalCost` hard coded instead of being calculated? It's easy enough, just sum up ever value for the years 10+ from now (hint: `if(year > 10 ) { ... } `). Also I'd suggest using a for-loop instead of a while. That way it's less easy to create an endless loop by accident.

Comment: `15000 + 15500 + 16000 + 16500` is wrong. The increase is 5% each year. This number grows over time. The first year 5% of $10,000 is $500. The next year 5% of $10,500 is $525.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to increase the amount 5% every year, instead of having `rate = 5`

You should have `rate = 1.05`.

With the rate as 1.05 you can do this

```
FeeAtYear1 = 10000*1.05^0 = 10000

FeeAtYear2 = 10000*1.05^1 = 10500

FeeAtYear3 = 10000*1.05^2 = 11025

FeeAtYear4 = 10000*1.05^3 = 11576.25

...

FeeAtYear10 = 10000*1.05^9 = ~16288.95
```

You don't even need a while loop.

```
TotalCost = 10000 *1.05^10 + 10000 *1.05^11 + 10000 *1.05^12 + 10000 *1.05^13;
```

Comment: sorry i didnt  understand..what do you mean i dont even need a while loop ?? im new in coding so i just know only while loop